# Snowpipe using SNS Topic - FIFO or Standard Type

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Does Snowpipe support SNS topics with FIFO or Standard or both?
I am trying to look for Snowpipe documentation that speaks if there is any limitation around the type of SNS topic, but could not find. Should I assume that Snowpipe supports both types?